# how to parse given data into a java object

Tags: java, json, parsing, hashmap, treemap

I want to parse below given data in to some java object, but I am not able to parse. String is as follows -

```
{\"objectsTree\":\"{\"Address\":[],\"Customer\":[\"Address\"]}\",\"objectsSequence\":\"[\"Customer\",\"Address\"]\"}
```

I have tried parsing this into HashMap and HashMap
but this is returning malformed JSON exception, and that is making sense, because of too many double quotes objects are ending abruptly. I want to parse this as follows-

```
{
"objectsTree":"{"Address":[],"Customer":["Address"]}",
"objectsSequence":"["Customer","Address"]"
}
```

here you can see that objectsTree is one object against one string and objectSequence is another. to be specific object tree is supposed to be a treemap , object sequence is supposed to be a ArrayList.

Any Idea how should I proceed.

code update-

package org.syncoms.backofficesuite.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //String json = "{\"Success\":true,\"Message\":\"Invalid access token.\"}";
    String json ="{\"objectsTree\":\"{\"Address\":[],\"Customer\":[\"Address\"]}\",\"objectsSequence\":\"[\"Customer\",\"Address\"]\"}";
    Gson jsonParser = new Gson();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    HashMap<String,Object> jo = (HashMap<String,Object>) jsonParser.fromJson(json, HashMap.class);
    System.out.println(jo);
    //Assert.assertNotNull(jo);
    //Assert.assertTrue(jo.get("Success").getAsString());


}
```

}

the error which I am getting -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Failed parsing JSON source: java.io.StringReader@201644c9 to Json
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:59)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:443)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:396)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:372)
    at org.syncoms.backofficesuite.controller.Test.main(Test.java:16)
Caused by: com.google.gson.ParseException: Encountered " <IDENTIFIER_SANS_EXPONENT> "Address "" at line 1, column 19.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "," ...
```

Comment: Post a complete minimal code example reproducing the error, and the complete stack trace of the error

Comment: I have added the code and error in the question, please check updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that the input is simply not a valid JSON String, and no JSON parser is going to accept it. the doulbe qoutes have to be escaped.
a Valid JSON String is as follows:

```
String jsonInput = "{\"objectsTree\":\"{\\\"Address\\\":[],\\\"Customer\\\":[\\\"Address\\\"]}\",\"objectsSequence\":\"[\\\"Customer\\\",\\\"Address\\\"]\"}";
```

and this can be parsed using, for instance, Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory tf = om.getTypeFactory();
JavaType mapType = tf.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, String.class);
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>)om.readValue(jsonInput, mapType);
System.out.println(map);
```

Printout is:

```
{objectsSequence=["Customer","Address"], objectsTree={"Address":[],"Customer":["Address"]}}
```

Comment: the code which I have given above is not able to parse this string as well

Comment: however, this is a valid JSON String. The example code is running fine. Try Jackson parser

Comment: The answer you have given is correct, however that is not solving my problem, But I got the idea from your inputs and i got the solution by changing the input pattern altogether. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could do that.

Firstly, if your data has always the same format you can simply create some methods which will create your TreeMap and ArrayList as required. You can do everything you want with String.replace(), StringTokenizer, matcher pattern. You can split your data into tokens and based on your needs place them in your required data structure. I find this way quite efficient and once you get to know better how to parse data and extract what you need, you can use this in many other examples.

If your data is formatted in JSON then there might be even easier ways of parsing it.You can decode it as Java object quite easy.

Comment: Thanks for you input, but in my scenario I am never going to change the string because it is too dynamic, I can receive anything but format will be same. means one treeMap and one ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

JSON string is not well formed one. Try as below

```
{
"objectsTree":{"Address":[],"Customer":["Address"]},
"objectsSequence":["Customer","Address"]
}
```

JSON key is always string &
JSON values can be:

```
•A number (integer or floating point)
•A string (in double quotes)
•A Boolean (true or false)
•An array (in square brackets)
•An object (in curly braces)
•null.
```

See the below code with well formed string and its output

```
String a = "{\r\n" + 
"\"objectsTree\":{\"Address\":[],\"Customer\":[\"Address\"]},\r\n" + 
"\"objectsSequence\":[\"Customer\",\"Address\"]\r\n" + 
"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap<String,Object> jo = (HashMap<String,Object>) mapper.readValue(a, HashMap.class);
System.out.println("result: "+ jo);

result: {objectsTree={Address=[], Customer=[Address]}, objectsSequence=[Customer, Address]}
```

with your json string

```
String json ="{\"objectsTree\":\"{\"Address\":[],\"Customer\":[\"Address\"]}\",\"objectsSequence\":\"[\"Customer\",\"Address\"]\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap<String,Object> jo = (HashMap<String,Object>) mapper.readValue(json, HashMap.class); 
System.out.println("result: "+ jo);

error :
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('A' (code 65)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@77d2b01b; line: 1, column: 20]
at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:943)
```

In your json string, for key objectsTree, the value is started with \"  and its matching \" is closed before string Address. This is causing the parse error.

> "{\"Address

The other two answers also saying that your json string is in invalid format.
I also added the supported json values for your reference.
If you change to correct format, any json parser will work,

Comment: even this is not parsing

Comment: added more detailed explanation. Look at my answer.